# ImportError: cannot import name ABCMeta - Python Error in PyDev on Linux

Tags: python, pydev

I came across this strange error while writing code using PyDev on Linux. Even a simple code like this produces error

```
print 'Hello World'
```

and the error is here

```
True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 62, in <module>
    import os
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 398, in <module>
    import UserDict
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 83, in <module>
    import _abcoll
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.py", line 11, in <module>
    from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
ImportError: cannot import name ABCMeta
```

my module is named *sample.py*. 
Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

My guess is that you have a file named either `abc.py` or `abc.pyc` in your working directory or PYTHONPATH and that one shadows the stdlib `abc` module.

Comment: thanks, I check again in the workplace folder and find out the evil abc.py. After deleting it, my program run perfectly.

Comment: Yup it worked for me. I had a file named abc.py. I just removed it and everything started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your python scripts's file name is "abc" and "abc" is a module of python's standard library.

Change the file name and run the script again, error will remove and script will work fine.