# python ImportError: No module named package

Tags: python, import

Given the following structure

```
abc
├── __init__.py
└── package
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.pyc
    ├── client.py
    ├── client.pyc
    ├── server.py
    └── server.pyc
```

when I run python in command line outside of `abc` and try to import package as below:

```
ImportError: No module named package
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are importing `package`, as opposed to `abc.package`, you need to put `abc` onto `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: BTW, I was having problem with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273373/importerror-cannot-import-name-abcmeta-python-error-in-pydev-on-linux was sort of scratching my head

Comment: @JamesLin: Oh wait, `abc` was the actual package name? The name `package` made me think all the names were made up for the purposes of the question. I guess this is where an SSCCE (http://sscce.org/) would have removed the ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get pip working again by doing the following :

```
cd /tmp/
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo apt-get purge -y python3-pip
sudo python3 ./get-pip.py
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```